# DataGrid finding a control

Tags: datagrid, findcontrol, hidden-field

HI

I have a DataGrid (yes would be nicer if it was a gridview but nothing i can do about that)

in the itemDataBound event i am adding a hidden field into the first cell of each row
I am setting its ID based on something, and then saving its clientID in a List for later attempts to get the value from it

but try as i might i cant find anything with findcontrol

have tried

here is the itemdatabound bit

```
foreach(page in datasource){
HiddenField hidOrder = new HiddenField();
hidOrder.ID = "order_" + page.Id.ToString();
hidOrder.Value = page.Ordering.ToString();
e.Item.Cells[0].Controls.Add(hidOrder);
idList.Add(hidOrder.ClientID);
}
```

then this is a button click event..

```
int numRows = FrontEndDataGrid.Items.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
  foreach(string hidID in idList){
    HiddenField hf = FrontEndDataGrid.Items[i].FindControl(hidID) as HiddenField;
    //ssadly this never finds anything
    //have also tried looping around the cells for each 'row' - no luck there either
  }
}
```

any ideas?

thanks

nat

Answer (score 0):

ok it seems i had the clientID , and i need the the plain id

so changed the idList.Add(hidOrder.ID); 
and all is well